# Setting ActiveStorage host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Right now I have a setup that allows users to point their apps directly to my Rails app using a CNAME (aka, point `www.example.com` to my app hosted at `www.example2.com`).

All that works great! But, I want to serve images up using my app `www.example2.com` as the host (for CDN reasons).

It seems like ActiveStorage is defaulting (and forcing...) the host to be the current host and not allowing me to change it.

I have:

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://www.example2.com'
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'https://example2.com'
```

and it works great for static assets! But, ActiveStorage `image_tag`'s are still using whatever domain the site is being viewed on, in this case `www.example2.com`.

Thoughts on how to make it ALWAYS serve using the asset_host?

Comment: Any solution to this yet? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: @Tintin81 unfortunately no, I ended up just not using `image_tag` anymore and setting my own host for the `img` tag using an environment variable. Sigh.

Answer (score 9):

Use `ActiveStorage::Current.host` which makes use of `CurrentAttributes`, a type of attributes that are set/reset on every request and can be used everywhere in your Rails app:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action do
    ActiveStorage::Current.host = 'https://example2.com'
  end
 end
```

If you want to use it outside of a controller, use `ActiveStorage::Current.set` to provide a host:

```
ActiveStorage::Current.set(host: "https://www.example2.com") do
  item.file_ttachments.first.service_url
end
```

Rails reference docs: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/SetCurrent.html